# Firemonkey: Loading a JPEG into any type of image control then saving to file or stream makes it smaller. Can this be avoided?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

In a mobile app one or more images (only jpeg/jpg) - either taken with built-in camera or selected from photo library - are displayed before uploading to a web service.

But loading an image into a FMX `TImage / TImageControl / TImageViewer` and saving it to stream (or file) makes it smaller, about 45%.

Any idea why this happens and is there a way to avoid the reduction in size ?

As asked for this is the simple test code, nothing special to it:

```
procedure TImageTest.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  aFile : string;
begin
  if not OpenDialog.Execute then
    Exit;
  // get jpg file name for loading
  aFile := OpenDialog.Filename;
  // load into TImage, TImageControl or TImageViewer
  ImageViewer.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(aFile);
  // and save to file for comparison
  ImageViewer.Bitmap.SaveToFile(aFile+'_2.jpg');
end;
```

Comment: Where did I ask for debugging help ? Or ask why code is not working ? It is a question on behaviour of firemonkey image components which can easily be reproduced with the simpliest test app.

Comment: Jpeg is not loseless format. Any loading, and then saving will introduce some quality loss. Why are you experiencing such loss in quality is hard to say without your exact code. If you need to upload image to web service, upload original file stream instead of intermediate representation from FMX controls.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: It seems that FMX has some issues with obeying Quality parameters passed in. I can see loss of quality under Windows with XE4, where quality drops from 97 to 90 and setting quality has no influence whatsoever. I don't know how it behaves on Android or iOS, but Windows side seems to be fixed in XE8 according to https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=705549

Comment: Thank you very much for these hints, I did not come across them, they are really helpfull and I will trace them further down.

Comment: Fundamental problem is your choice to decompress and recompress. Those actions are not inverse to each other, compression is not lossless. Do not do that.

Comment: If you use the actions TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction or TTakePhotoFromCameraAction, you have a bitmap in the OnDidFinishTaken event. Resized to MaxHeight / MaxWidth (property of the 'taken' actions). I have no idea if it's losing the same quality as you described.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution to avoid losing image quality is by not relying on the visual controls to store your data. Instead, keep a background object containing the raw image file, and only use the visual controls to display this image to the user. When it comes to saving the image, save it from this background object rather than the visual control.

The same concept applies for about all aspects of programming - visual controls are only meant for visual display to the user, not for storing data.

Comment: Images aren't handled as files on mobile devices, data come as TBitmap objects either from camera or library. Displaying is just for final check before upload not meant for storage . But on the other hand any image control just uses TBitmap for storing images - so where is the difference to keeping the image data in another background TBitmap object ? And if  stored in a temp file before upload I am back to the problem: reduction in size.

Comment: Visual controls or not aren't really the issue. You are recoding the file. Why?

Comment: Where did I say I am recoding the file ?

Comment: It's there in the code in the question. You decompress when you load it, recompress when you save. Perhaps you don't fully grasp what your code does and what it means for compression to be lossy.